# Select from two tables and arrange them in desc order of a common column in the two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables
The first table(messages table):
message_id, participant_id, time(default: current_timestamp), message_body.

The second table(allocation table):
allocation_id, participant_id, time(default: current_timestamp), info.

The participant_id in the two tables are the same, how can I select all the info from the two tables and arrange then in descending order of "time".

E.g: select * from table a join table b where participant_id= 1 desc(time);

I want it so that it will arrange it based on the time.
I hope my message is clear. If you need more explanation, I'm always available.

Comment: Both tables have `time` column, which one you want to order by? Messages time or allocation time?

Comment: If you join the two tables you will have two time columns in each row. You could order the query by a function of the two columns (say min, max or average).

Comment: Please add sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements) and your desired result for that data to clarify what you want. Please also add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

select * from table a 
join table b 
**on a.participant_id=b.participant_id**
where a.participant_id= 1 
**order by  b.time desc**

Comment: This will fail as the column time is ambiguous between the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to sort by time in the allocations.

```
Select m.id, a.allocation_id, a.info, m.message_body, a.time, b.time
FROM messages as m
INNER JOIN allocation as a
ON m.participant_id=a.participant_id
ORDER BY a.time DESC;
```

If you want to sort by time in messages:

```
Select m.id, a.allocation_id, a.info, m.message_body, a.time, b.time
FROM messages as m, allocation as a
INNER JOIN allocation as a
ON m.participant_id=a.participant_id
ORDER BY m.time DESC;
```

Comment: Consider to use the explicit `... INNER JOIN ... ON ...` syntax.